# Erro migrae : TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found

Tags: python, django

Estou tendo dificuldades ao executar `python manage.py migrate`, ate chega a criar as tabelas mais no final me retorna o seguinte erro :

> TypeError: Required argument 'year' (pos 1) not found

alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Comment: você já avia feito a migração alguma vez? se sim, você pode editar ou apagar os arquivos da pasta `migrate` (exceto __init__.py), e apagar o banco de dados.

Comment: sim ja havia feito  isso que acho mais estranho , ai quando vou entra no admin do django  me retorna a tela de erro .

Comment: isso aconteceu muitas vezes comigo tbm, da uma olhada no comentário acima, editei com uma possível solução

Comment: Brumazzi fiz aqui como vc me indicou , apaguei as **migrations** ate onde não estava dando erro , fui apagando uma por uma ate que a **migrate** rodasse com sucesso

Comment: use o comando `python manage.py makemigrations` e depois `python manage.py migrate`. isso vai gerar as novas configurações e deve ficar tudo ok

Comment: Você poderia colocar o stacktrace do erro, assim seria mais fácil e simples para te ajudar

Comment: Higor, posta os seus models, o que está recebendo o erro e os que estão relacionados a ele.

Comment: Higor, pelo que eu pesquisei pela descrição do erro que você postou. Parece que você está tentando atribuir uma data padrão como `datetime.date`. Tente utilizar `datetime.date.today`. Isso é tudo que eu consigo tirar do que você postou, por favor poste seu model para que possamos ser mais precisos em nossas respostas.

Comment: Galera muito obrigado mais ja deu certo aqui o problema e que eu não estava chamando o `.now() `no meu `datetime` que fica `datetime.now()`

Comment: e tive também que volta a migrate que não havia dado erro `para python manage.py migrate ####0035`

Comment: Cara, não se apaga as migrations que o django gera, a menos que o caso seja realmente necessário.
Cada migração que você faz, vale a pena você perder 1 min lendo ela para ver o que ela faz com o seu banco de dados.